# Add a dynamic nft mint price

Tags: nft, price

Good afternoon family! i need help! I'm launching my ERC721A collection very soon, and i need to add a function, just to set different prices on the PUBLIC sale. Let me explain... I will have Freemint(whitelist) for a group(3.000 nfts), and the Public Sale with 2 levels, first 2.000 will be at 0.02eth and last 5.000 at 0.04eth. My question is... how can i put a "modifier or function" in the publicsalemint function (line 114: publicSalePrice) which allow me to set different prices depending of the amounts of nft that people has minted in public sale?? Thanks you a lot in advance! Iattached full code here.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "./ERC721A.sol"; 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract JOSE is Ownable, ERC721A, ReentrancyGuard {
 
     using Strings for uint;

   //Minting steps to set

    enum Step {
        Before,
        PublicSale, //1 (whitelist mint and public mint will be at the same time, 2 boxes in the web)
        SoldOut  //2
        
    }    
    //State Variables

    string public baseURI;
    Step public sellingStep;
      
    //Constant variables 
     
    uint16 private constant MAX_SUPPLY = 10000; //Max Supply
    uint16 private constant MAX_WHITELIST = 3000; //WHITELIST
    uint16 private constant MAX_PUBLIC = 7000;   //PUBLIC PASS (First 2.000 AT 0.02 and 5.000 at 0.04)
  
    
    uint8 private maxMintPerWhitelist = 3; 
    

     //Variable for the merkle tree root
    bytes32 public merkleRoot;
      
    //Minting prices
    uint128 public wlSalePrice = 0 ether;
    uint128 public publicSalePrice = 0.02 ether; (must be later a function to update the price to 0.04 once 2.000 nft are minted in public sale)
    
    //Mapping for the amount of tokens that address can mint in whitelist 

    mapping(address => uint) public amountNFTsperWalletWhitelistSale;
    

    //Constructor. MerkleRoot for the whitelist and the metadata baseUri of hidden stickies
     
    constructor(bytes32 _merkleRoot, string memory _baseURI) ERC721A("STICKY FACES", "STICKY") {

        merkleRoot = _merkleRoot;
        baseURI = _baseURI;

         }
     
     //Modifier to prevent minting/attacks from another SmartContract
       
    modifier callerIsUser() {
        require(tx.origin == msg.sender, "The caller is another contract.");
        _;
    }

      
      //Function verifying if the msg.sender is FreeMint listed in the array of the MerkleTree. Despues añadir otro root para whitelist
      
    function isValid(bytes32[] memory merkleproof, bytes32 leaf)public view returns (bool){
         return MerkleProof.verify(merkleproof, merkleRoot, leaf);
    }

    //WhiteListMint with merkleproof seted in Javascript

    function whitelistMint(uint8 _quantity, bytes32[] calldata merkleproof) external payable callerIsUser{

        require(sellingStep == Step.PublicSale, "Sale is not activated");
        require(isValid(merkleproof, keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender))),"Not in whitelist List");
        require(amountNFTsperWalletWhitelistSale[msg.sender] + _quantity <= maxMintPerWhitelist, "You can only get 3 NFT on the Whitelist Sale");
        require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_WHITELIST, "Max whitelist supply exceeded");
        require(msg.value >= wlSalePrice * _quantity, "Not enought funds");
        amountNFTsperWalletWhitelistSale[msg.sender] += _quantity;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, _quantity);
        }
         
   
     //Function Public Mint. Need to add a function to first 2.000 public at 0.02 and last 5.000 at 0.04
     
    function publicSaleMint(uint256 _quantity) external payable callerIsUser {
       
        require(sellingStep == Step.PublicSale, "Public sale is not activated");
        require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_WHITELIST + MAX_PUBLIC, "Max supply exceeded");
        require(msg.value >= publicSalePrice * _quantity, "Not enought funds");
        
         _safeMint(msg.sender, _quantity);
    }

    //Function GIFT to OGs and Collabs

    function gift(address _to, uint _quantity) external onlyOwner {
         require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Reached max Supply");
        _safeMint(_to, _quantity);
    }

    //Function to set the real baseUri once want to reveal

    function setBaseUri(string memory _baseURI) external onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _baseURI;
    }


    //Function to set step of the sale (1,2,3,4). 

    function setStep(uint _step) external onlyOwner {
        sellingStep = Step(_step);
    }

    //Token Uri by ID

    function tokenURI(uint _tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(_tokenId), "URI query for nonexistent token");
        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, _tokenId.toString(), ".json"));
    }

    //Whitelist merkletree update

    function setMerkleRoot(bytes32 _merkleRoot) external onlyOwner {
        merkleRoot = _merkleRoot;
    }

       
    
    //Withdraw.

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner nonReentrant {
    (bool os, ) = payable(owner()).call{value: address(this).balance}('');
    require(os);
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide source code as text, that way it will be much easier to try suggesting changes.

Comment: Good morning Ismael,your right. I just upload the full code. Thank you!!